# Nebensatz but the verb not in last position?

Tags: word-order, verbal-complex

Here's the passage:

> Widerwillig war er an Bord gegangen. Eigentlich nur, weil er sich
>   keine Blöße ***hatte*** geben wollen.

shouldn't it have been:

> ...weil er sich keine Blöße geben wollen ***hatte***.

?

In the same novel, another passage reads as follows:

> Was den Kommissar jedoch besonders missmutig machte,
>   war die Tatsache, keine weiteren Informationen zu besitzen als
>   nur das eine Faktum: dass eben drei Leichen ***gefunden worden
>   waren***.

What's the difference between the two cases, if any?

Answer (score 2):

No. That is because if a Standard German clause has bare infinitives, they are the last words in that clause.

> Er wollte sich keine Blöße **geben**. *(wollen needs an infinitive)*
>
> Er hatte sich keine Blöße **geben wollen**. *(Plusquamperfekt with Ersatzinfinitiv of wollen)*
>
> … weil er sich keine Blöße hatte **geben wollen**. *(same as a dependent clause)*

---

There is an exception in Bavarian and some Austrian dialects, though:

> Er hatte sich keine Blöße **geben gewollt**.
>
> … weil er sich keine Blöße hatte **geben gewollt**.

But this one affects the (regular) past participle only, which is replaced by the *Ersatzinfinitiv* in Standard German. That rule *nothing but infinitives after an infinitive* is very strict in Standard German.

Comment: But my question was about the position of 'hatte', because 'wollen' here is not really an infinitive but rather a past participle, right?

Comment: Sure it is. It's the **Ersatzinfinitiv**. And the rule is infinitives come last.

Comment: @Janka What are you talking about? There is no such rule as "nothing but infinitives after an infinitive" about dependent clauses! "...weil er kein Risiko *eingehen* **wollte**" is pefectly normal German.

Comment: You are right, I was out of my mind. The modals itself are an exception.

Comment: In the same novel, another passage:" ... nur das eine Faktum: dass eben drei Leichen gefunden worden waren." What's the different thing here? Why wasn't it written: "dass eben drei Leichen waren gefunden worden."??

Comment: *Gefunden werden* is passive voice. *Waren* is past tense of the copula (*sein*) and *worden* is past tense of *werden*. There is no infinitive here. Better create another question for this.