# Word order in subordinate clause when using modal verb and subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctive, modal-verb, subordinate-clause

I have been pondering about this sentence from "Die Verwandlung":

> »Ich weiß«, sagte Gregor vor sich hin; aber so laut, daß es die
> Schwester hätte hören können, wagte er die Stimme nicht zu erheben.

The word order here is throwing me off a little:

> so laut, daß es die Schwester hätte hören können

"So loud, that the sister could have heard it."

I would have expected something like: "so laut, daß es die
Schwester hören können hätte", i.e. with the auxiliary verb at the end. For example, in other tenses/moods:

> So laut, dass sie es hören konnte.

"So loud that she could hear it."
or

> So laut, dass sie es gehört hätte

"So loud that she would have heard it".

I looked for references but found no answer to my questioning. Can anyone point to the rule that results in this word order? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nebensatz but the verb not in last position?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39472/nebensatz-but-the-verb-not-in-last-position) Also: [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49676/3-verbs-in-one-sentence-correct-order/49678#49678) [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58535/finites-verb-vor-dem-doppelten-infinitv/58545#58545) [3](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49676/3-verbs-in-one-sentence-correct-order/49678#49678)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this in a main sentence first:

> Sie hätte es hören können.

If you set a sentence with a modal verb like "Sie kann es hören" into perfect tense (in Konjunktiv here), this for some strange reason is done by using the infinitive instead of the participle, so that's why it's not "Sie hätte es hören gekonnt" but "Sie hätte es hören können". This is called "Ersatzinfinitiv".

https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Ersatzinfinitiv

If you have an Ersatzinifinitiv in a subordinate clause, the two infinitives always  follow the conjugated auxilliary verb:

> dass sie es hätte hören können
> [conjunction] [subject] [object] [conjugated aux. verb 2 (always a form of "haben")] [main verb infinitive] [modal verb 1 infinitive]

Other examples:

> Er musste noch warten, weil der Chef es hat unterschreiben müssen.
> Der Text wäre mit Schriftgröße 5pt so klein gewesen, dass man ihn nicht mehr hätte lesen können.
> Sie behaupten, dass die Stimmzettel hätten früher verschickt werden müssen und nicht mehr hätten gezählt werden dürfen.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean the two infinitives follow the conjugated auxiliary verb?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've edited