# Verb positions with subjunctive at the end of a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

The passage in question comes from "Der Schimmelreiter" by Theodor Storm. Here it is:

> [Er suchte] für ihn Arbeiten aus, die seinem noch nicht gefesteten Körper **hätten gefährlich werden können**.

My question is about the word order at the end of this sentence. Since a "*,die ...*"-type subordinate clause will send the verb to the end, we can unpack it as a full sentence like this:

> [Diese] Arbeiten **können** seinem noch nicht gefesteten Körper **hätten gefährlich werden**.

This confuses me, however, because, as far as I am aware, the correct form is "[*sie*] *hätten können*", not the other way around, so the above sentence seems weird to me. In other words, I would have written it as

> [Diese] Arbeiten **hätten** seinem noch nicht gefesteten Körper **gefährlich werden können**.

What is the reason for the original word swap? And what makes it correct?

Comment: See also: [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/word-order-in-subordinate-clause-when-using-modal-verb-and-subjunctive-mood/61715) [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39472/nebensatz-but-the-verb-not-in-last-position) [3](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49676/3-verbs-in-one-sentence-correct-order/49678) [4](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58535/finites-verb-vor-dem-doppelten-infinitv/58545)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion seems to be about which verb is the conjugated predicate in

> [Er suchte] für ihn Arbeiten aus, die seinem noch nicht gefesteten Körper hätten gefährlich werden können.

A subordinate clause does send the predicate to the end, but if the predicate uses an Ersatzinfinitiv like it does here, the infinitives still come after the conjugated verb.

So in this case *hätten* is the conjugated verb, it's 3rd person plural Konjunktiv II of *haben*. *Werden können* are the Infinitives. *Gefährlich* could also come before *hätten* here ("... gefährlich hätten werden können"), but the author decided to draw it near to *werden* to which it belongs.

Which means the correct way to unpack it to a full sentence is exactly what you assumed:

> [Diese] Arbeiten hätten seinem noch nicht gefesteten Körper gefährlich werden können.

Comment: There is only one *Ersatzinfinitiv*: *können* instead of *gekonnt* in combination with the perfect auxiliary. *Werden* is just an infinitive, required by *können*.

Comment: @David Vogt: you're right, I corrected it.