# Unusual word order: Passive mit Modalverben im Plusquamperfekt

Tags: verb, word-order, modal-verb, passive, pluperfect

My German textbook gives the following solution to an exercise where correct verb forms need to be filled in:

*Nachdem das Ziel **hatte erreicht werden können**, sollen die Sieger gefeiert werden.*

I have also found the following sentence online:

*Die Pilotin erklärte, warum vor dem Start beim Wetterdienst die Wettervorhersage
**hatte abgefragt werden müssen**.*

**Question.** Why is the conjugated verb not at the end of the auxiliary clause? Should it not be '**Nachdem das Ziel  erreicht werden können hatte**, ...', so that the verb that changes comes at the end? Isn't it the rule in German?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verb positions with subjunctive at the end of a sentence](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/63190/verb-positions-with-subjunctive-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) (see also the answers linked there)

Answer (score 2):

This is a special word order rule that kicks in when you have an *Ersatzinfinitiv* and dependent clause word order. The conjugated form of *haben* leads the row of infinitives then.

This is mandatory for the modals but there are some verbs for which the use of *Ersatzinfinitiv* is optional, e.g. *sehen*. Let me demonstrate it with that verb:

> Du weißt, dass er es nicht **kommen gesehen hat.**
>
> Du weißt, dass er es nicht **hat kommen sehen.**

If you use the Ersatzinfinitiv, you have to place *haben* before the infinitives.

---

A similar rule kicks in for Futur I but it's fully optional.

> Du weißt, dass er es nicht **kommen sehen wird.**
>
> Du weißt, dass er es nicht **wird kommen sehen.**

Answer (score 2):

This somewhat advanced position of the finite verb in a clause-final complex predicate is called "Oberfeld". A detailed explanation is here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammatik#Reihenfolge_der_Verben

For a shorter account: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldermodell_des_deutschen_Satzes#Feinere_Einteilungen_f%C3%BCr_die_Position_der_Verben

I would turn around Janka's answer: Ersatzinfinitiv happens when a nonfinite verb is governed from the Oberfeld.